# function that calculates confidence interval

Tags: r, function, confidence-interval

I have two questions:
First,I a qualitative variable Type `class(Type)=table` with different frequencies of categories, say

```
Type
    Type1          Type2            Type3
      150           4900                4
```

and a statistic for each of the categories I calculated before in another function (class is data frame) :

```
df
     Var1           Freq
1     Type1            0.1800
2     Type2            0.1130
3     Type3            0.2500
```

I want to calculate the confidence interval for each category automatically in a function that returns two vectors of the upper and lower bounds of the confidence intervalls. The formula for the confidence interval would be:
`df[1, 2] + 1.96*sqrt(df[1, 2]*(1 - df[1, 2])/t[[1]])`so that the function extract the corresponding values from the table and the dataframe.
Do I have to use for loop like this?

```
ci <- function(stat, Type){
  p <- tapply(stat, Type, function(x) sum(x)/length(x))
  df <- as.data.frame(as.table(p))
  t <- table(Type)
    for (i in nrow(df)) {
      for (j in t)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Charlotte, though somewhat outdated, this page has some code that may be helpful to you http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/ especially the summarySE function.

Comment: package ‘summarySE’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

`summarySE` is function in the package [`Rmisc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmisc/Rmisc.pdf). By this function you can calculate CI for different categories. Current version 1.5 is available for R 3.4.0